# Futuristic sci-fi dystopian anime about crime fighting woman who suffers from flashbacks

Tags: story-identification, anime

I only remember certain random scenes from this anime but this is what I remember:

- Main character is a woman with brown hair in a ponytail. In one scene, her friends hands her a drink or something and when she stares at the label, she gets a flashback. She continues to get flashbacks throughout the show.
- Older man with a young girl (I think his daughter?) walking down a path covered with cherry blossoms. In another scene, they are seen eating in their home. No dialogue in these scenes.
- There's a blonde (???) character whose eyes aren't very visible and they seem to be kept captive somewhere. Brief interactions with brown haired main character.
- Scene with brown haired main character standing and observing the city from a high altitude. She seems to be wearing a futuristic suit of some sorts. Guess she's a crime fighter? All I remember from this show is that the art is really beautiful and there is a lot of cityscapes. I remember it being very abstract.

Comment: Any ideas on what the production year could be? Are there any other shows which have the same or very similar art style you could list? Do you know any other characters that look just like those, if you remember?

Comment: A few more details would be good, like setting, plot points, or how many years ago you saw it. Maybe even the color of the futuristic suit you mentioned? What you've come up with so far makes me think of *Burst Angel* (about a group of female mercenaries who fight crime in a futuristic city). Though it may also be *Psycho-Pass* (fights crime, brown haired woman, cityscape) or *Ghost in the Shell* 1995 (woman protagonist with futuristic outfit/tools, citsyscape, crime fighter). Maybe even Rebecca Lee from *Black Lagoon*? Do any of these have a similar tone/art style?